# AngularJS using http.get with ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple weather web application using angularJS. I am using a weather API and I want to make an input box so page loads the weather according to the city that the user inputs.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="./myApp3.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Weather Center</h1>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <form>
      Please enter your location: <input type="text" ng-model="location">
    </form>
        <p id="field">
          Location: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.name }}, {{ myData.data.sys.country }}</span>
        </p>
        <p id="field">
          Current Conditions: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.weather[0].description }}</span>
        </p>
        <p id="field">
           Temperature: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.main.temp | kelvinToFahrenheit | number: 0 }}&deg;F</span>
        </p>
        <p id="field">
          Pressure: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.main.pressure }} mb</span>
        </p>
        <p id="field">
          Wind Speed: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.wind.speed }} mph</span>
        </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $scope.location + ",uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myData = response;
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.myData = "Something went wrong";
    });
});

app.filter('kelvinToFahrenheit', function() {
  return function(kelvin) {
    return (parseFloat(kelvin) - 273.15) * 1.80 + 32.00;
  };
});
```

I had it working with no input box and I just had "London" where the "$scope.location" is inside the http.get(). But when i use this code and type London into the input box, it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to wrap the `$http` in a function

```
$scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $scope.location + ",uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.myData = response;
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.myData = "Something went wrong";
        });
}
```

Then use an event like `ng-submit` to call this function

```
<form ng-submit="getData()">
  Please enter your location: <input type="text" ng-model="location">
  <button>Get Data</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ng-keyup event to to detect when the value has changed.

I made the following to your code,

I added `ng-keyup="getLocation()"` to your input box.

I placed your http function inside the `$scope.getLocation` function.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/WraEOY

HTML:

```
<h1>Weather Center</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    Please enter your location:
    <input type="text" ng-model="location" ng-keyup="getLocation()">
  </form>
  <p id="field">
    Location: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.name }}, {{ myData.data.sys.country }}</span>
  </p>
  <p id="field">
    Current Conditions: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.weather[0].description }}</span>
  </p>
  <p id="field">
    Temperature: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.main.temp | kelvinToFahrenheit | number: 0 }}&deg;F</span>
  </p>
  <p id="field">
    Pressure: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.main.pressure }} mb</span>
  </p>
  <p id="field">
    Wind Speed: <span id="result">{{ myData.data.wind.speed }} mph</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.getLocation = function(){
  $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $scope.location + ",uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myData = response;
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.myData = "Something went wrong";
    });


};

});


app.filter('kelvinToFahrenheit', function() {
  return function(kelvin) {
    return (parseFloat(kelvin) - 273.15) * 1.80 + 32.00;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't watching for changes to `location`. Use `$scope.$watch('location', ...)`.

Comment: would I call the $scope.watch() before or after the http.get()? Also, what are the other arguments after $scope.watch('location', ...